# SQL Server 2017 : Invalid length parameter

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO #NEWSTATICFILTER
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        (SELECT STATICNAME FROM #STATICFILTER WHERE IDNUM = @ic) AS STATICNAME,
        (SELECT 1  
         FROM [CoSD].[ERSCommodityDataSeries] CD 
         WHERE CD.ERSCommodity_ID IN (LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(INT, (SELECT SUBSTRING (M.STATICNAME, CHARINDEX('(', M.STATICNAME, 0) + 1, (CHARINDEX(')', M.STATICNAME, 0) - CHARINDEX('(', M.STATICNAME, 0) - 1)) 
                                                                FROM #STATICFILTER M 
                                                                WHERE IDNUM = @ic))))) 
           AND (CD.ERSCommodity_SourceSeriesID NOT LIKE '%(N%' OR CD.ERSCommodity_SourceSeriesID IS NULL)),
        (SELECT 1  FROM [CoSD].[ERSCommodityDataSeries] CD 
         WHERE CD.ERSCommodity_ID IN (LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(INT, (Select SUBSTRING (M.STATICNAME,CHARINDEX('(',M.STATICNAME,0)+1,(CHARINDEX(')',M.STATICNAME,0)-CHARINDEX('(',M.STATICNAME,0)-1)) FROM #STATICFILTER M WHERE IDNUM =@ic )) )) )AND CD.ERSCommodity_SourceSeriesID LIKE '%(N%' AND CD.ERSCommodity_SourceSeriesID IS NOT NULL),
```

When I am trying to execute this query, it throws this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

I know this is a repeated question, but I am not getting any idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You are trying to do a lot in one go. In my view the first thing to do is to make sure your charindex's are actually producing something, i.e. getting a match. So try a simpler sql statement (just the select, forget the insert at this stage), get that working correctly, and then build on it.

Comment: @MandyShaw thank you so much!  I know it is alot,but this is part of a code which is 4000 lines, and tight deadlines, I would really appreciate if you can give me an idea

Comment: The only idea is that in one or more rows, charindex is returning negative number which is causing the number to be passed into the `substring` function to be < 0 ... i would expect the error to come from this code block. If this the parentheses doesn't exist, -1 would be returned... `CHARINDEX('(',M.STATICNAME,0)-1)`. This is essentially resulting in `substring(columnname,<starting position>,-1)`. Like so... `select substring('a',1,-1)`

Comment: So a case statement should help ? or any other workaround ?

Comment: Move all that parsing stuff outside this query. All those `substring`s are not related to any other tables then `#STATICFILTER`. It's totally unreadable now.

Comment: You need to think about this in relation to your data, which is why there is a limited amount we can do to help. What do you /want/ to happen when there is no match, i.e. charindex fails to return >0? Should this actually be happening at all, given your data, i.e. does it imply a problem further back in your code? Simplify the code down, check each section of code is getting the input you expect and producing the output you expect, and you will get there. Sorry but there is no alternative to debugging this properly.

Comment: The work around is to know your data. I know you are hoping for a quick fix here and someone just to spit out an answer, but you need to take a step back, start over, and work through your problem. We told you where the problem is, so you can aim your focus there.

Comment: Incorporation of the CASE function within either the LEFT or SUBSTRING function and thus not generating the error.. Check this link for more info: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-537.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is answerable without your data as the exact behavior of the query is going to be dependent on the data. As far as I can tell from what you've provided of the query the issue seems to be that you have one or more entries for M.STATICNAME that doesn't have a ) in it. You are trying to calculate the Length for the two SUBSTRINGs using position of the ) in the string minus the position of the ( in the string. If the ) doesn't exist this becomes 0 - some value resulting in a negative value. It appears that the string does have a ( or the whole thing would become 0 - (0-1) which would just be 1.

Look for something in #STATICFILTER where it is like '%(%' and not like '%)%'.